# Permission denied to write on live server

Tags: php, xml, permissions, sitemap, chmod

I have created a PHP script for my PHP ecommerce website , that whenever I run this script it replaces new sitemap inside sitemap.xml file.  this script works great locally but when running this script on live server i got this error:

{warning: file_put_contents(../sitemap.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/mywwebsite.com/sitemap-maker.php on line 45}

I tried to give full permission to my file sitemap.xml, also trying resolve it manually. is there someone can guide in this regard.

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to access the sitemap one level above the current working directory, so it's looking in `/var/www`. Change the path to the sitemap.xml to something a bit more absolute

Comment: There are a lot of missing details here. What OS is your server running ? And what is the web server that you're using ?

Comment: on local machine its working perfectly on apache-xamp, but on live its creating error which is mentioned above. live web server is: Nginx

Comment: Is it a VPS or a shared hosting?